# MapBox Heatmap hide outside boundaries

Tags: heatmap, mapbox-gl-js

I'm creating a heatmap of the United States and the designers want to "stop" the color from bleeding outside the US borders. So under Texas, the colors would reach the edge of the state and just stop.

Is this possible?

I tried creating another layer that included Mexico, Canada, and the Pacific/Atlantic Oceans, but heatmaps render after and I can't find out how to set a render priority, either.

edit: Here is an image that shows the desired effect:
[image]

And here is my code, minus some irrelevant data:

```
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'accessTokenString';
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map-heatmap',
    style: 'mapbox://uri/for/styles',
    center: [-95.922211, 37.881266],
    zoom: 3.15,
    minZoom: 3.15,
    maxZoom: 3.15,
    maxPitch: 0,
    dragPan: false,
    dragRotate: false
});

map.on('load', function() {

    map.addSource('states', {
        'type': 'geojson',
        'data': '/path/to/us-states-contiguous.geojson'
    });

    map.addLayer({
        'id': 'state-fills',
        'type': 'fill',
        'source': 'states',
        'layout': {},
        'paint': {
            'fill-color': '#F2F2F2'
        }
    });

    map.addSource('mexico', {
        'type': 'geojson',
        'data': '/path/to/mexico.geojson'
    });

    map.addLayer({
        'id': 'mexico',
        'type': 'fill',
        'source': 'mexico',
        'layout': {},
        'paint': {
            'fill-color': '#fff'
        }
    });

    map.addSource('heatmapCoordinates', {
        'type': 'geojson',
        data: {
            "type": "FeatureCollection",
            "features": {/* JSON coordinates */}
        }
    });

    map.addLayer({
        'id': 'myHeatmap',
        'type': 'heatmap',
        'source': 'heatmapCoordinates',
        'layout': {},
        'paint': {
            'heatmap-weight': 1,
            'heatmap-color': [
                'interpolate',
                ['linear'],
                ['heatmap-density'],
                0,
                'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
                1,
                'rgba(0, 183, 79, 1)',
            ],
            'heatmap-radius': 100,
            'heatmap-opacity': .5
        }
    }, 'mexico');

    map.addLayer({
        'id': 'state-borders',
        'type': 'line',
        'source': 'states',
        'layout': {},
        'paint': {
            'line-color': 'rgba(43, 43, 43, .5)',
            'line-width': .25
        }
    });
});
```

For some reason, the borders that I draw over the heatmap appear "on top" of it. But when I try a layer to "fill", (like with Mexico above), it won't appear over the heatmap gradients, always underneath.

**So how would I be able to "clip" the heatmap's shading outside of the US borders to achieve the above image's desired effect?**

Comment: It's not very clear what you're asking. Can you include screenshots and your style code?

Comment: @SteveBennett I added an image and a code snippet. If that's not clear enough, let me know and I can revise again. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your heatmap renders above the clip polygons because you're adding it to the map afterwards.

You just need to change the order of the two `addLayer()` calls.

Comment: So, the second parameter for the map.addLayer() function is supposed to load it "underneath" (or before) the item whose ID is listed. But even if I try loading the heatmap before the "mexico" layer, the heatmap still appears on top of it.

Comment: Oh I missed that, sorry. I'm surprised by this behaviour. Can you put it in in a codepen?